# How to benchmark Node.js streams?

Tags: javascript, node.js, benchmarking

How can I benchmark [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) in Node.js?

I've tried [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Transform = require('readable-stream').Transform;
var util = require('util');
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

// my super uppercase stream
function Uppercase(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Uppercase))
    return new Uppercase(options);

  Transform.call(this, options);
}

Uppercase.prototype = Object.create(
  Transform.prototype, { constructor: { value: Uppercase }});

Uppercase.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  chunk = chunk.toString().toUpperCase();
  this.push(chunk)
};

// start benchmarking
suite.add('stream test', function() {
  var reader = fs.createReadStream('in.txt');
  var parser = new Uppercase();
  var writer = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt');
  reader.pipe(parser).pipe(writer);
})
// add listeners
.on('cycle', function(event) {
  console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'));
})
// run async
.run();

suite.run();
```

But I get the error

```
Unhandled stream error in pipe
```

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to benchmarking? In other words, does `var reader = fs.createReadStream('in.txt'); var parser = new Uppercase(); var writer = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt'); reader.pipe(parser).pipe(writer);` throw the same error when you try it outside of the benchmark?

Comment: Just saw that I called `run()` twice but that wasn't the error. @MathiasBynens The code is working fine outside the benchmark environment. I've also added an `error` event handler for the `reader`. Now initial error is gone and I get `[Error: OK, open 'my\path\to\data.json'`

Comment: what is your node version and which OS are you using ?

Comment: node v0.8.18 and mac os v10.7.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code encounter this error, you could see it by listen to error on reader and writer :

```
[Error: EMFILE, open 'out.txt'] errno: 20, code: 'EMFILE', path: 'in.txt'
[Error: EMFILE, open 'out.txt'] errno: 20, code: 'EMFILE', path: 'out.txt'
```

This is caused by the fact that streams are asynchronous and without explicit callback on when they end. So you are pretty much creating thousand and thousands of pipe stream between in.txt and out.txt untill the system tells you they are too many files descriptor open.

So, I'll guess that by "benchmarking streams in Node", what you want to want to calculate is the time it takes to do synchronously perform this operation :

```
reader.pipe(filter).pipe(writer)
```

In that case you will need to :

- use the defer option of benchmark [benchmarkjs documentation](http://benchmarkjs.com/docs#options_defer)
- be sure when pipe operation is over [node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)

The code for this answer has been tested with node 0.10.0, but I guess that the only difference should be in the name of the module which holds `Transform` :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
var Benchmark = require('benchmark');
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

var i = 0;

// my super uppercase stream
function Uppercase(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Uppercase))
    return new Uppercase(options);

  Transform.call(this, options);
}

Uppercase.prototype = Object.create(
  Transform.prototype, { constructor: { value: Uppercase }}
);

Uppercase.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  chunk = chunk.toString().toUpperCase();
  this.push(chunk)
};



// start benchmarking
suite.add('stream test', {
  'defer' : true,
  'fn' : function (deferred) {
    var reader = fs.createReadStream('in.txt');
    var parser = new Uppercase();
    var writer = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt');

    reader.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    writer.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
    reader.on('end', function  (argument) {
      // Wait until reader is over and then close reader and finish deferred test
      writer.end();
      deferred.resolve();
    });

    reader.pipe(parser).pipe(writer, {'end': false});
  }
})

//  listeners
.on('cycle', function(event) {
  console.log(String(event.target));
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'));
})

// run async
.run();
```

Comment: Looking good. Will try the code tonight. Thought that async operations might cause the problem but didn't know about the `defer` option. Thanks!

Comment: Just one small improvement: call `deferred.resolve()` in `parser.on('end', function(){})` instead `reader.on('end')` as the latter might close the `writer` before my `parser` is done.

Comment: I still haven't found the answer why. But the parser does not emits the end signal. Even if we call the function like this `reader.pipe(parser,{'end': false }).pipe(writer, {'end': false});`. I'll look into it more deeply.

Comment: parser does not emit any event in our case. I have tried with all the readable and writable streams event and nothing. I am not actually sure if it is a feature or not.