# What is the performance of piping a stream in node.js?

Tags: node.js, sockets, stream

I have a TCP server written in Node.js.  When a socket is received on its server socket, the process passes off the socket to a process pool.  It either forks or reuses a previously forked process.  It then passes the received socket to that other process using ChildProcess.send().  This gives complete control of the socket to the child process.

I am considering taking a different approach, but I'm concerned about the potential performance trade-offs.  I would like instead to pipe the socket to the child process either through stdin or a unix domain socket or maybe a pipe.  There are a number of reasons why this approach would be preferable in my particular domain, but I won't belabor this question with those details.

So I am left to wonder about the performance characteristics of the pipe() method on a Node.js stream.  Is the piping of the stream handled at the system level, or does Node.js have to read every byte from one stream and send it down the destination?  There are a few system calls (i.e. splice()) that provide some level of zero-copy streaming of file descriptors.  Does Node.js use some sort of mechanism like that or is it manual?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a read of [this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2817-the-affect-of-back-pressure-when-piping-data-into-multiple-writable-streams-in-node-js.htm), which highlights how

> when it comes to streams, things are only as fast as the slowest
>   stream in the workflow

Also, have a read of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15521845/1521933) explaining how to benchmark streams in node.